# MySQL query and subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS GINTO,
(
   (SELECT COUNT(price)*9.99 FROM sms_logs WHERE price = '200000')+
   (SELECT COUNT(price)*3.99 FROM sms_logs WHERE price = '60000')+
   (SELECT COUNT(price)*1.99 FROM sms_logs WHERE price = '24000')+
   (SELECT COUNT(price)*0.99 FROM sms_logs WHERE price = '11000')
) AS USD,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE FROM sms_logs 
WHERE DATE >='2015-03-20' AND DATE <= '2015-04-30'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

I want show data as:

```
 GINTO  ||   USD  ||   DATE
2222000 ||   200  || 2015-03-23
3366000 ||   300  || 2015-03-24
11000   ||   10   || 2015-03-25
```

But result with that query:

```
 GINTO  ||   USD ||   DATE
2222000 || 284.65|| 2015-03-23
3366000 || 284.65|| 2015-03-24
11000   || 284.65|| 2015-03-25
```

with USD column it shows a summary of all records. Why?

Comment: You need to provide some sample data and the logic of the expected result set,best is sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `count` calls are run in separate queries, with no `group by` clause, so they are applied on the entire table, regardless of the "main" query's goruping. One way to solve this would be to get rid of the subqueries and bring them into the "main" query:

```
SELECT   SUM(price) AS GINTO,
         SUM(CASE price WHEN '200000' THEN 9.99
                        WHEN '60000'  THEN 3.99
                        WHEN '24000'  THEN 1.99
                        WHEN '11000'  THEN 0.99
              END) AS usd,
         DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date 
FROM     sms_logs 
WHERE    date >='2015-03-20' AND date <= '2015-04-30'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS GINTO,
SUM(case when price = '200000' then 1 else 0 end*9.99)+
SUM(case when price = '60000' then 1 else 0 end*3.99)+
SUM(case when price = '24000' then 1 else 0 end*1.99)+
SUM(case when price = '11000' then 1 else 0 end*0.99) AS USD,
DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE FROM sms_logs 
WHERE DATE >='2015-03-20' AND DATE <= '2015-04-30'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATE,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try below query-

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS GINTO, 
      (COUNT(IF(price='200000',price,NULL))*9.99 +  
       COUNT(IF(price='60000',price,NULL))*3.99 + 
       COUNT(IF(price='24000',price,NULL))*1.99 + 
       COUNT(IF(price='11000',price,NULL))*0.99) AS USD, 
DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Date' 
FROM sms_logs 
WHERE date_col >='2015-03-20' AND date_col <= '2015-04-30'
GROUP BY DATE(date_col)
```